# method call inside method with ref keyword

Tags: c#, ref

Hello have an issue when trying to call method inside another method which holds ref element as a parameter.Method "replaceWordInLine" creates new Line and I call it in method "findLine". I should give "replaceWordInLine" method line argument, just don't know how to do it with ref.

```
findLine(string dataFile, ....)
{
  string[] text = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(dataFile.....;
  foreach(string line in text)
  {
   replaceWordInLine(ref , disconnectors, word, wordBegining);
  }
}


 replaceWordInLine(ref string e, string disconnectors, string word, int wordBegining)
    {
        findWordInLine(e, s, out word, out wordBegining);
        string findWord = word;
        StringBuilder newLine = new StringBuilder();
        e.Remove(word.Length,pr);
        newLine.Append(word + " " + e);
    }
```

Comment: `replaceWordInLine(ref line, disconnectors, word, wordBegining);` ?

Comment: @AgentFire, try'ed that . Shows an error : Cannot use 'line' as a ref or out value because it is a foreach iteration variable.

Comment: The code is not really complete... `s` is undefined, `disconnectors` is unused, `e.Remove(word.Length,pr)` doesn't really make sense

Comment: Declare a local variable then, assign `line` to it. Define a `List`, gather all the results in there.

Comment: @AgentFire, maybe the issue is that I can't call method inside foreach loop ? is that possible ?

Comment: Can you please point out what your problem is, and what you are trying to achieve? Why are you using ref?

Comment: You are all giving solutions that may let the code work, but are (at least i think) far from desirable in this case. Please clarify why to use your solution

Comment: @NickGames, I need to find word which has atleast three specific letters and replace them in to the beginning of the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string s = line;
replaceWordInLine(ref s, disconnectors, word, wordBegining);
```

Comment: Exactly what I had typed in the comments a minute too late, this is the answer - short and simple.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a for i loop instead of a foreach

This :
      string[] text = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(dataFile.....;
      foreach(string line in text)
      {
       replaceWordInLine(ref , disconnectors, word, wordBegining);
      }

Would become :

```
  string[] text = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(dataFile.....;
  foreach(int i =0; i<text.Length; i++)
  {
   replaceWordInLine(ref text[i] , disconnectors, word, wordBegining);
  }
```

And you're good to go

Comment: Ferreti , yup thought about that too, but I imagined that it would pick a word by word that line and with foreach I would pass only line